# postgresql jsonb uses a lot of memory

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

We tested a 40 Mb json insert into a `jsonb` column and it took 1.3Gb of memory.
While inserting this 40 Mb json as `text` took only 500Mb of memory.

I understand that a json tree takes a lot of memory, but **why is this multiplier so enormous**?
And, **are there alternatives**? Can I prepare jsonb structure, so without having to `::jsonb` cast it. That's where the memory consumption comes from.

Some code fragments to help explaining the idea:

```sql
create table my_test (data jsonb, data2 text);
```

`insert_jsonb.sql` contains

```sql
insert into my_test (data) values ('{.......40mb }'::jsonb);
```

`insert_text.sql` contains

```sql
insert into my_test (data2) values ('{.......40mb }'::text);
```

then run it via psql:

```sh
psql -f insert_jsonb.sql # takes 1.3Gb memory
```

```sh
psql -f insert_text.sql # takes 500Mb memory
```

Comment: How do you measure the memory consumption? Do you measure it on the client or on the server?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe for testing I ran `psql` on the server itself (same docker container). In production pg is limited to 1Gb and it crashes. I measure it with `docker stats` on the postgres container.

Comment: Well, that explains why you see the memory used several times - both the client and the server have to hold the data. You should figure out on which side the problem is. Still, the discrepancy is too much to be explained by that. You'll have to investigate closer where the problem is.